# Select multiple columns using decode

Tags: oracle11g

I have 6 columns with same value as either of 0,1,2,3. I want to display the result such as 0 represents SUCCESS, 1 or 2 represent failure and 3 represents NOT APPLICABLE. So if in DB the values are :

```
col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F 
0     |   1   |  2    |  0    |   3   |    2
```

Output should be :

```
col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F
S     |    F  |  F    |     S |  NA   | F
```

Is it possible to do it through decode by selecting all the columns at once rather than selecting them individually?

Comment: If u want to display the result in one column it is possible. But, your output suggests you want the result to be in multiple columns. So my answer is its not possible. You ll have to use decode/case multiple times

Comment: It's *possible* by unpivoting the table, decoding the individual rows that produces, and then pivoting back to the original layout; but it's almost certainly not worth the extra work, and it'll be simpler and clearer to just decode each column individually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you just need a case expression (or decode, if you prefer, but that's less self-documenting than a case expression), along the lines of:

```
case when some_col = 0 then 'S'
     when some_col in (1, 2) then 'F'
     ...
     else some_col -- replace with whatever you want the output to be if none of the above conditions are met
end
```

or maybe:

```
case some_col
     when 0 then 'S'
     when 1 then 'F'
     ...
     else some_col -- replace with whatever you want the output to be if none of the above conditions are met
end
```

So your query would look something like:

```
select case ...
       end col_a,
       ...
       case ...
       end col_f
from   your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to do it through decode by selecting all the columns at once rather than selecting them individually?*
**No**

However, besides using pivot, the only solution I see would be using PL/SQL: 
1.This is how I simulated your table

```
SELECT *
FROM (WITH tb1 (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e, col_f) AS 
(SELECT 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT *
      FROM tb1)
```

2.I would append the columns together with a comma between them and save them into a table of strings

```
SELECT col_a || ',' || col_b || ',' || col_c || ',' || col_d || '.' || col_e || ',' || col_f
FROM (WITH tb1 (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e, col_f) AS (SELECT 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT *
      FROM tb1)
```

3.Then I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace your values one row at a time

```
SELECT REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (REPLACE ('0,1,2,0,3,2', 0, 'S'), '[1-2]', 'F'), 3, 'NA') COL_STR 
FROM DUAL
```

4.  Using dynamic SQL I would update the table using rowid or whatever you intend to do. I made this SQL which will separate the string into columns

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS COL_A, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS COL_B,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 3) AS COL_C, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 4) AS COL_D,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 5) AS COL_E, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (COL_STR, '[^,]+', 1, 6) AS COL_F
FROM tst1)
```

All of this is very tedious and it could take some time. Using `DECODE` or `CASE` would be easier to look at and interpret and thus easier to maintain.